# Determine if mouse is still in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mouse

I'd like to be able to use jQuery to trigger an event if the mouse has been stationary for a certain amount of time.

Any ideas? I'm not even sure where to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [idleTimer plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) which could be used for this purpose. And here's a [nice demo](http://paulirish.com/demo/idle-timer) of the plugin in action.

Comment: I like your solution because it's sensitive to both mouse and keyboard. Also it might come with some implicit cross-browser compatibility benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Hook up a [mousemove()](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) handler on the document and [set a timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout). When timeout elapses, do your thing. Whenever the mouse moves again, [cancel the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) so it will fire relative to the last mouse movement.

This is a combination of jQuery and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

jquery 1.4 offers a new method [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) for that