# jQuery - detect if the mouse is still?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, mouse

I was wondering if there was a way to detect if the mouse is idle for like 3 seconds in jQuery. Is there a plugin that I am unaware of? Because I don't believe there to be a native jQuery method. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if mouse is still in javascript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487939/determine-if-mouse-is-still-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can listen to the `mousemove` event, start a timeout whenever it occurs and cancel any existing timeout.

```
var timeout = null;

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Mouse idle for 3 sec');
    }, 3000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mw2gD/)

This can be very easily done without jQuery as well (only binding the event handler here is jQuery-specific).

Comment: Probably want to set `timeout` back to `null` after the timer fires to avoid doing an invalid `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: @jfriend00: Doesn't matter, really. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-cleartimeout Even the `null` check.

Comment: @FelixKling OK, so what I did was used this in conjunction with the jScrollPane plugin so that if the user is idle for 3 seconds, the scrollbar fades out of visibility. How can I make it to where it re-appears when the user is not idle? (e.g. when he/she moves the mouse?) I tried making an entirely separate function but it is not working.

Comment: @ModernDesigner: Just put in inside the event handler. The `mousemove` event is triggered (as the same says) whenever the mouse moves, i.e. it is not idle anymore. Just have a look how I remove the text in the demo.

Comment: @FelixKling ahh, thanks! That's it. And I did take a look at your Possible Duplicate Proposition, and the plugin linked there seems very helpful as well. I'll take both of those into consideration. Thanks again!

Comment: @minitech - if you want to send invalid handles to `clearTimeout()` go ahead.  I don't program that way nor would I counsel others to do so.  In my book, it's sloppy programming and it takes one extra line of code to follow a better general practice.

Comment: @jfriend00: I never said I did, but you were pointing it out like it mattered and it turns out that it doesn't, is all. I've always avoided doing that too.

Answer (score 8):

No need for a plugin, or even for jQuery at all:

```
(function() {
    var idlefunction = function() {
          // what to do when mouse is idle
        }, idletimer,
        idlestart = function() {idletimer = setTimeout(idlefunction,3000);},
        idlebreak = function() {clearTimeout(idletimer); idlestart();};
    if( window.addEventListener)
        document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousemove",idlebreak,true);
    else
        document.documentElement.attachEvent("onmousemove",idlebreak,true);
})();
```