# generate a scipt to check each n seconds if the mouse is moving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a javascript function that call it self each n seconds of time 
so when calling this function if the mouse is mouving do not make ajax request , else : make ajax call 
theory :

```
function CheckIfMouseIsMoving(){
if(!MouseMoving){
// Make ajax call
}
else{return false;}
}

setInterval(CheckIfMouseIsMoving,3000);
```

Comment: So, where is your actual question?

Comment: how to check if mouse is moving or not

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt what i did here is theory , i need the real code how to check if mouse is not moving

Comment: At a single instance of time mouse is always stopped.You want to check if its moved in last 3 seconds?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Comment: @MaheerAli No I want to call a function each 3 seconds to check if the mouse is moving in the same moment  the function is called

Comment: @Roy how to check if mouse is not moving , this one is detecting the mouse movement

Comment: But as @MaheerAli correctly says, if you have a single frame of observation, there can't be any movement. So the best you can do is `if(was_moving_last_few_µs)`

Comment: @Kaiido I understand now , so what is the solution to check if the mouse is not moving when calling the function (first moment) and before 1 second of calling the function .

Comment: @Kaiido how to do that ?

Comment: @Kaiido i just want to make sure that i do not call ajax request when user is moving the mouse around .

Comment: For last second, `let moving = false; let t; addEventListener('mousemove', e=>{ moving=true; clearTimeout(t); t=setTimeout(()=>moving=false, 1000); })` for higher rate (smaller delay), `let moving = false; let r; addEventListener('mousemove', e=>{ moving=true; cancelAnimationFrame(r); r=requestAnimationFrame(()=>moving=false, 1000); })`

Comment: @markdibe read https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/ and learn about positions... the mouse has an x and y so...  that's what you need to see if is moving or not.

Comment: @Roy the very fact that the event fires means that it is moving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - detect if the mouse is still?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094272/jquery-detect-if-the-mouse-is-still)

Comment: @Kaiido i tried the one you told me with a function , the problem that he gets that the mouse is always not moving : here is the code 
let moving = false;
        let r;
        addEventListener('mousemove', e => { moving = true; cancelAnimationFrame(r); r = requestAnimationFrame(() => moving = false, 1000); });

        function CheckIfMouseIsMoving() {
            if (!moving) {
                alert('mouse is not moving');
                GetPeopleNotEnteredYet();
                GetEnteredPeople();
            }
        }

        setInterval(CheckIfMouseIsMoving, 3000);

Comment: Yeah, my rAF solution was assuming an other event than setInterval, the setTimeout one does work though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` and `document.onmousemove`

```js
let MouseMoving = false;
let tm;
document.onmousemove = function(e){
  MouseMoving = true;
  if(tm) clearTimeout(tm)
  tm = setTimeout(() => MouseMoving = false,1000);
}


function CheckIfMouseIsMoving(){
  if(!MouseMoving){
    console.log("Mousse was not moving")
  }
  else{
    console.log("Mousse was moving")
    return false;
  }
}

setInterval(CheckIfMouseIsMoving,3000)
```

Comment: You have to move the mouse inside the 'run code' area.

Comment: @MaheerAli you are right i have deleted the first comment